# How can I obtain this matrix quickly in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix

Is there a way of obtaining the matrix `matFinal` quickly by avoiding the following long procedure?

```
    s1 = PauliMatrix[1]; s2 = PauliMatrix[2]; s3 = PauliMatrix[3];
u = {{a^2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a b}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {a b, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b^2}};
m11 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s1, s1]];
m12 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s1, s2]];
m13 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s1, s3]];
m14 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s2, s1]];
m15 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s2, s2]];
m16 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s2, s3]];
m17 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s3, s1]];
m18 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s3, s2]];
m19 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s1, s3, s3]];

m21 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s1, s1]];
m22 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s1, s2]];
m23 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s1, s3]];
m24 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s2, s1]];
m25 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s2, s2]];
m26 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s2, s3]];
m27 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s3, s1]];
m28 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s3, s2]];
m29 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s2, s3, s3]];

m31 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s1, s1]];
m32 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s1, s2]];
m33 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s1, s3]];
m34 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s2, s1]];
m35 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s2, s2]];
m36 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s2, s3]];
m37 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s3, s1]];
m38 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s3, s2]];
m39 = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[s3, s3, s3]];

matFinal = {{m11, m12, m13, m14, m15, m16, m17, m18,
   m19},        {m21, m22, m23, m24, m25, m26, m27, m28, m29}, {m31,
   m32, m33, m34, m35, m36, m37, m38, m39}}
```

Note that `mi(jk) = Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[si, sj, sk]]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
matFinal2 = Join @@@ Array[Tr[u. KroneckerProduct @@ (PauliMatrix /@ {##})] &, {3, 3, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{2 a b, 0, 0, 0, -2 a b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, -2 a b, 0, -2 a b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a^2 - b^2}}
> ```

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ matFinal2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
>  2 a b & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 a b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & -2 a b & 0 & -2 a b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2-b^2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternative version without `@, @@, @@@, /@, ##`:

```
matFinal3 = Map[Flatten][
   Table[Tr[u.KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[i], PauliMatrix[j], PauliMatrix[k]]], 
     {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]];

matFinal3 == matFinal2 == matFinal
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, but this notation @, @@, @@@, /@, ## is too compact and I am not able to understand what is happening:)

Comment: Could you write in couple of lines on how this works?

Comment: Read the documentation for `Prefix`, `Function`, `Map`, and `Apply`. In general, in Mathematica highlight a symbol or operator that you don't understand (e.g., `@@`) and press `F1` for help.

Comment: @User101, see if the alternative version using `Table` is easier to follow.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261958/how-to-obtain-this-matrix-quickly-in-mathematica/261959#261959):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

s = Array[PauliMatrix, 3];

u = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> a^2, {1, 8} -> a b, {8, 1} -> a b,
  {8, 8} -> b^2}];

(matFinal =
   Partition[Tr[u . KroneckerProduct[##]] & @@@ Tuples[s, 3],
    9]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]